# how to adjust padding in html/css?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas, media-queries, html5-video

I want to give padding on image to close to the remaining section but nothing works for me.
I am trying:

```
 float-right or padding-right:250px; // but nothing happent and also it will spoil my mobile view also.
```

Kindly check what I am doing:

```css
    .fontProfile {
    font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
    /* min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    color: #262626;
    padding-bottom: 3rem; */
    }
    .imgProfile {
    display: block;
    }

    .containerProfile {
    max-width: 93.5rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    }

    .btnProfileIn {
    display: inline-block;
    font: inherit;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: inherit;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    .btnProfileIn:focus {
    outline: 0.5rem auto #4d90fe;
    }


    /* Profile Section */

    .profile {
     padding: 5rem 0;
    }

    .profile::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    }

    .profile-image {
    float: left;
    width: calc(33.333% - 1rem);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 3rem;
    }

    .imgProfile {
    border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .profile-user-settings,
    .profile-stats,
    .profile-bio {
    float: left;
    width: calc(66.666% - 2rem);
    }

    .profile-user-settings {
     margin-top: 1.1rem;
    }

    .profile-user-name {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 3.2rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    }

    .profile-edit-btn {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    line-height: 1.8;
    border: 0.1rem solid #dbdbdb;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    padding: 0 2.4rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    }

    .profile-settings-btn {
     font-size: 2rem;
     margin-left: 1rem;
    }

    .profile-stats {
    margin-top: 2.3rem;
    }

    .profile-stats li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-right: 4rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    .profile-stats li:last-of-type {
     margin-right: 0;
    }

    .profile-bio {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-top: 2.3rem;
    }

    .profile-real-name,
    .profile-stat-count,
    .profile-edit-btn {
    font-weight: 600;
    }



    /* Media Query */

    @media screen and (max-width: 40rem) {
    .profile {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        padding: 4rem 0;
    }

    .profile::after {
        display: none;
    }

    .profile-image,
    .profile-user-settings,
    .profile-bio,
    .profile-stats {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }

    .profile-image {
        width: 3.7rem;
    }

    .profile-user-settings {
        flex-basis: calc(100% - 10.7rem);
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin-top: 1rem;
    }

    .profile-user-name {
        font-size: 2.2rem;
    }

    .profile-edit-btn {
        order: 1;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 1rem;
    }

    .profile-edit-btn {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .profile-bio {
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        margin-top: 1.5rem;
    }

    .profile-edit-btn,
    .profile-bio,
    .profile-stats {
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }

    .profile-stats {
        order: 1;
        margin-top: 1.5rem;
    }

    .profile-stats ul {
        display: flex;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1.2rem 0;
        border-top: 0.1rem solid #dadada;
        border-bottom: 0.1rem solid #dadada;
    }

    .profile-stats li {
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        flex: 1;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .profile-stat-count {
        display: block;
    }
    }



    @supports (display: grid) {
    .profile {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
        grid-column-gap: 3rem;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .profile-image {
        grid-row: 1 / -1;
    }



    .profile-image,
    .profile-user-settings,
    .profile-stats,
    .profile-bio {
        width: auto;
        margin: 0;
    }

    @media (max-width: 40rem) {
        .profile {
            grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
            grid-row-gap: 1.5rem;
        }

        .profile-image {
            grid-row: 1 / 2;
        }

        .profile-user-settings {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
            grid-gap: 1rem;
        }

        .profile-edit-btn,
        .profile-stats,
        .profile-bio {
            grid-column: 1 / -1;
        }

        .profile-user-settings,
        .profile-edit-btn,
        .profile-settings-btn,
        .profile-bio,
        .profile-stats {
            margin: 0;
        }
    }
    }
```

```html
    <header>

    <div class="container containerProfile">

        <div class="profile">

            <div class="profile-image">

                <img class="imgProfile" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513721032312-6a18a42c8763?w=152&h=152&fit=crop&crop=faces" alt="">

            </div>

            <div class="profile-user-settings">

                <h1 class="profile-user-name fontProfile">janedoe_</h1>

                <button class="btnProfileIn profile-edit-btn">Edit Profile</button>

                <button class="btnProfileIn profile-settings-btn" aria-label="profile settings"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

            </div>

            <div class="profile-stats">

                <ul>
                    <li><span class="profile-stat-count">164</span> posts</li>
                    <li><span class="profile-stat-count">188</span> followers</li>
                    <li><span class="profile-stat-count">206</span> following</li>
                </ul>

            </div>

            <div class="profile-bio">

                <!-- <p><span class="profile-real-name">Jane Doe</span></p> -->

            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- End of profile section -->

     </div>
     <!-- End of container -->

     </header>
```

I am having so much gap between Image and name. I want that div come close to the remaining part.

[This is the problem - The gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yla4T.png)

Any idea or suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: hello plz can you explain more or the final result you want to add padding or you want to fix the gap between image and text

Comment: @godfather I want to fix the gap between image and text.

Comment: hello sarah have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

try on your css part

```
.imgProfile {
padding-right:250px }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding padding to the `profile-image` what you can do is to try to make the remaining part come close to the image div and for this you can do this:

```
.profile-user-settings {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-right: -35px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex for the image div and justify the content to the end.

```
.imgProfile {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: @Sumner Evans display:flex; justify-content:flex-end; not working. Kindly suggest why it is not working in my code. It should work. Your suggestion is good but unfortunately did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you include margin-left:200px(or whatever you want), you can close the pic to the remaining section.Like this:

`.imgProfile { display: block; margin-left: 200px; }`

Answer (score 0):

in this part of the
css

```
`@supports (display: grid){ .profile {
                                                                                       
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
    grid-column-gap: 3rem;
    align-items: center;}`
```

change like i did grid-template-columns:1fr 2fr; to auto 1fr ; and you can remove grid-column-gap

Comment: @Sarah did this helped?